# bind DataGridViewComboBoxColumn in C# from DB

Tags: c#

I had a column in my `DataGridView` which is a `DataGridViewComboboxColumn`, and I need to bind this column from a database table which is also has a column with values like 1,2,3. Based on these values  the combo box must display different values, ie. if 1 "Manager" and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Let's use [Northwind database](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=06616212-0356-46a0-8da2-eebc53a68034&displaylang=en) as our test data.

[image]

**These are the steps:**

1. [Configure datasource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233813.aspx).
2. Drag a DataGridView to the form.
   [image]
3. Drag Products onto the DatagridView.
   [image]
   [image]
4. Right click on DatagridView - Edit Columns.
5. Select CategoryID, change column type to DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.
6. Choose the datasource(Category table), display member(CategoryName) and value member(CategoryID) for the column. Click OK to apply changes.
   [image]
7. Build and run the project. Voila~
   [image]

Comment: ok thats wokk..  But ineed to show the text display on the combo box is only conditional (ex:- if the table value is one then it is "Manager")